# How to access values from Runspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable

Tags: vb.net, powershell

I am running a PowerShell script using System.Management.Automation, and the script runs fine.

I am then pulling the results from the script using the command below and I can see the results in my variable sResults when looking at it in the debugger.

```
Dim sResults = ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.GetVariable("results")
```

And I can loop through each item in SResults using

```
For Each sResult In sResults
```

But I can't work out how to actually obtain any of the values stored in this variable within my code, I have tried using TryCast to convert it to a PSObject, but still at a loss.

As you can see in the screenshot below all the information I want is there, I just need to know how to get it out, namely the value of Exception and PSComputerName (or) TargetObject initially.

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated, spent hours search forums and googling etc but can't seem to find much reference to GetVariable or similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by very helpful person here :) = https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2459073-how-to-access-values-from-runspace-sessionstateproxy-getvariable